# Javascript issue. Need help with a loop and .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I a search result page. This search result page is a table. I can not change the html of the page. This is the html:

```
<table class="product-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <dl>
                <dt>
                    <h1>Item</h1>
                </dt>

                <dd class="title fn">
                    <a class="url" href="/product.jsp?id=EHS_FR_BS-PK-409674&amp;navAction=jump&amp;navCount=0">
                        Pratique de l'accouchement, 5ème Edition
                    </a>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <dl>
                <dt>
                    <h1>Item</h1>
                </dt>

                <dd class="title fn">
                    <a class="url" href="/product.jsp?id=EHS_FR_BS-PK-409674&amp;navAction=jump&amp;navCount=0">
                        Pratique de l'accouchement, 5ème Edition
                    </a>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My Question**

But i want in the dd class title fn. A new  element. This a element is a link to more information of the page. The  element must get the href of the a class=url element.

I make this javascript:

```
 $("table.product-table .pricing").append('<a class="information" href="" title="plus d’information">plus d’information</a>');
```

But how can i fix this better. And how can i put the href of the class url in the new a element that i append.

Do you understand my question??

**Thanks for helping!**

Comment: why are you using a class "pricing" inside the jquery selector? this elements does not seem to exist in your given html

Comment: You already have a link to the resource, why are you duplicating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("dd.title.fn").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.append('<a class="information" href="' + $this.find(".url").attr("href") + '" title="plus d’information">plus d’information</a>');
});
```

Does this help you? Check out this link for more information on `each` method which might help you getting the url of each link you want to append.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/